# How to copy Outlook mail message into excel using Macros

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I've searched all google and I've tried some suggestions from stack overflow to achieve results but they seem to not work towards my specific goal. Wondering if anyone here can help me.

I work in a call center where I receive emails with agents productivity data on an hourly basis and it's beginning to be a lot of manual work. How can I get a macro to copy the email body and paste it to an excel sheet automatically? or I can run it daily.

This is an example of how the data looks

Hourly Productivity

[image]

The specific data I need to copy:

```
Agent Login | Agent Name | Average Talk Time | Total Talk Time | Calls Answered | Total ACW
```

I would also love to be able to include the date and hours of the productivity if possible? on the picture you will be able to see the time for it. (8:00 AM - 9:00 AM)

I would really appreciate any help in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should pretty much do what you want.

```
Sub Extract()
 On Error Resume Next
 Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
 Set mynamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("mapi")
 Set myfolder = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

Set xlobj = CreateObject("excel.application.14")
 xlobj.Visible = True
 xlobj.Workbooks.Add
 xlobj.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "Statusmail"

'Set the header
 xlobj.Range("a" & 1).Value = "Absender"
 xlobj.Range("a" & 1).Font.Bold = "True"
 xlobj.Range("b" & 1).Value = "Date"
 xlobj.Range("b" & 1).Font.Bold = "True"
 xlobj.Range("c" & 1).Value = "Task"
 xlobj.Range("c" & 1).Font.Bold = True
 xlobj.Range("d" & 1).Value = "Planed-date"
 xlobj.Range("d" & 1).Font.Bold = True
 xlobj.Range("e" & 1).Value = "deadline"
 xlobj.Range("e" & 1).Font.Bold = True
 xlobj.Range("f" & 1).Value = "finished"
 xlobj.Range("f" & 1).Font.Bold = True
 xlobj.Range("g" & 1).Value = "time effort"
 xlobj.Range("g" & 1).Font.Bold = True
 xlobj.Range("h" & 1).Value = "description"
 xlobj.Range("h" & 1).Font.Bold = True

For i = 1 To myfolder.Items.Count
  Set myitem = myfolder.Items(i)
  msgtext = myitem.Body

  xlobj.Range("a" & i + 1).Value = myitem.To
  xlobj.Range("b" & i + 1).Value = myitem.ReceivedTime
  xlobj.Range("c" & i + 1).Value = msgtext


 Next
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

here is some code to get you started, it processes all selected messages, so select just one message of interest

it prints the message body type and body text into the "immediate window"

```
Public Sub exploreEmailMessage()

    Dim currentItem As Object     ' drag "currentItem" onto "Watches" window, or use: right-click ... Add Watch

    For Each currentItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection    ' check Watches window after this line is executed
        Stop
        If currentItem.Class = olMail Then

            Debug.Print "************************************"
            Debug.Print currentItem.ReceivedTime
            Debug.Print "************************************"
            Debug.Print Array("Unspecified", "Plain", "HTML", "RichText")(currentItem.BodyFormat)
            Debug.Print "************************************"
            Debug.Print currentItem.Body
            Debug.Print "************************************"
            Debug.Print currentItem.HTMLBody
            Debug.Print "************************************"   ' copy text in "immediate window" and paste into text editor for analysis

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Jsotola thank you for taking the time to help me, this is useful but I was more looking to export the files automatically because when copying to inmediate window it disrupts the formats on how its pasted there.

Comment: @StevenNouel, the code that i posted was meant as a starting point. you said that you would like to extract the table data from the emails. so you need to start by finding out the format of the email body, and go from there. if it is HTML, then parse it as a web page. if it is RichText, then use another technique. etc....